# tabview with dialog fragment android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException:

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context

Hi I am trying to display a dialog fragment in one of my tab but when I click that button it is showing error as

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window --
>   token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@4137eb30 is
>   not valid; is your activity running?

But same code is working in a normal activity(means without tab). I have tried different solutions but none is working.

Below is the code.

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    static Context mn;
    static Activity ji;

    static MyDialogFragment newInstance() {

        String title = "is this  success";

        MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", title);

        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String title = getArguments().getString("title");
        Dialog myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setTitle(title)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ((Code) getActivity()).okClicked();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                }).create();

        return myDialog;
    }
}
```

The activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mthird.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                OpenDialog();
            }

        });

    }

    void OpenDialog() {
        MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
        myDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "myDialogFragment");
        System.out.println("cancelbutton");
    }

    public void okClicked() {
        String textok = " Title";
        MySecondDialog myDialogFragment = MySecondDialog.newInstance(textok);
        myDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "myDialog");
    }

    public void cancelClicked() {
        String textcancel = "Reason";
        MySecondDialog myDialogFragment = MySecondDialog.newInstance(textcancel);
        myDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "myDialogFragment");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using your parent activity context Like

```
(Activity(mn)).getParent()
```